# Saving string with xml

Tags: c#, xml, string

why if I save my variables and load them back then companyName and playerName is this: System.Xml.XmlElement, instead of what I write? Other variables works just fine. I am struggling with this for a while, so I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

```
public void LoadGamePrefs()

{

    string filepath = "c:/Users/gamePrefs.xml";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();


    if(File.Exists (filepath))
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(filepath);
        XmlNodeList transformList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("GamePrefs");


        foreach (XmlNode transformInfo in transformList)
        {
            XmlNodeList transformcontent = transformInfo.ChildNodes;    

            foreach (XmlNode transformItems in transformcontent)
            {                  
                if(transformItems.Name == "firstStart")
                {
                    firstStart = bool.Parse(transformItems.InnerText);
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "drawFirstGui")
                {
                    drawFirstStartGui = bool.Parse(transformItems.InnerText); 
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "companyName")
                {
                    companyName = transformItems.InnerText; 
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "playerName")
                {
                    playerName = transformItems.InnerText; 
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "money")
                {
                    scriptMainBackground.money = int.Parse(transformItems.InnerText);
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "year")
                {
                    year = int.Parse(transformItems.InnerText);
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "month")
                {
                    month = int.Parse(transformItems.InnerText); 
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "week")
                {
                    week = int.Parse(transformItems.InnerText);
                }
                if(transformItems.Name == "day")
                {
                    day = int.Parse(transformItems.InnerText); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public void SaveGamePrefs()    {

    // Accesing other script and variable
    GameObject mainBackground = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainBackground");

    ScriptMainBackground scriptMainBackground = mainBackground.GetComponent<ScriptMainBackground>();        

    string filepath = "c:/Users/gamePrefs.xml";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();


    if(File.Exists (filepath))
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(filepath); 
        XmlElement elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;    

        elmRoot.RemoveAll(); // remove all inside the transforms node.
        XmlElement elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("GamePrefs");  

        XmlElement gamePrefs_firstStart = xmlDoc.CreateElement("firstStart"); 
        gamePrefs_firstStart.InnerText = firstStart.ToString();             

        XmlElement gamePrefs_drawFirstGui = xmlDoc.CreateElement("drawFirstGui");
        gamePrefs_drawFirstGui.InnerText = drawFirstStartGui.ToString();             

        XmlElement gamePrefs_companyName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("companyName");
        gamePrefs_companyName.InnerText = gamePrefs_companyName.ToString();            

        XmlElement gamePrefs_playerName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("playerName");
        gamePrefs_playerName.InnerText = gamePrefs_playerName.ToString();            

        XmlElement gamePrefs_Money = xmlDoc.CreateElement("money"); 
        gamePrefs_Money.InnerText = scriptMainBackground.money.ToString();        

        XmlElement gamePrefs_Year = xmlDoc.CreateElement("year"); 
        gamePrefs_Year.InnerText = week.ToString();            

        XmlElement gamePrefs_Month = xmlDoc.CreateElement("month"); 
        gamePrefs_Month.InnerText = week.ToString();             

        XmlElement gamePrefs_Week = xmlDoc.CreateElement("week"); 
        gamePrefs_Week.InnerText = week.ToString();    

        XmlElement gamePrefs_Day = xmlDoc.CreateElement("day"); 
        gamePrefs_Day.InnerText = day.ToString();             

        //XmlElement gamePrefs_GenreNumber = xmlDoc.CreateElement("genreNumber"); 
        //gamePrefs_Day.InnerText = genreNumber.ToString();


        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_firstStart);
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_drawFirstGui);
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_companyName);
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_playerName);
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_Money); 
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_Week); 
        elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_Day); 
        //elmNew.AppendChild(gamePrefs_GenreNumber);
        elmRoot.AppendChild(elmNew);     

        xmlDoc.Save(filepath); // save file.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code - remove vertical spacing to make it readable

Comment: Do you have xsd for this file ?

Comment: perhaps you should simply use the serialization api, or the [settings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C) or [any](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16953/XML-configuration-files-made-simple-at-last) dedicated library. There's too much code repetition. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
XmlElement gamePrefs_playerName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("playerName");
gamePrefs_playerName.InnerText = gamePrefs_playerName.ToString();
```

You are setting the elements inner text property to the `XmlElement` class + namespace by invoking `.ToString()` on the object.

Your intention is not clear but i assume you need to set the `InnerText` property to the `playerName` variable and not the string representation of the `XmlElement` object.

```
XmlElement gamePrefs_companyName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("companyName");
gamePrefs_companyName.InnerText = companyName; 

XmlElement gamePrefs_playerName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("playerName");
gamePrefs_playerName.InnerText = playerName;
```

Note that the `ToString();` call is unesseccary here as the `playerName/companyName` variables already appear to be strings judging from the code in `LoadGamePrefs()`

Comment: No problem, if this answers your question [please consider accepting it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it may help others in future.